# Multiplication of matrices. Performance

Tags: c++, performance

I have a program for multiplication of square matrices. It  also, I think the program's performance by the formula (number of operations) / (run time). Why is the growth dimension of the matrix decreases performance? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;

 double getsec(){
   struct timeval t;
  gettimeofday(&t,NULL);
   return t.tv_sec+t.tv_usec*0.000001;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
double begintime=getsec();

int n;
if(argc==2)n=atoi(argv[1]);
else n=3;

int**a=new int*[n];
double**b=new double*[n];
double**c=new double*[n];
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    a[i]=new int [n];
    b[i]=new double [n];
    c[i]=new double [n];
}

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        a[i][j]=i+1;
        b[i][j]=1/(j+1.);
        c[i][j]=0;
    }

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        c[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];

double qty_of_operations = (double)2*n*n*n;

cout<<n<<"  c11="<<c[0][0]<<"  c1n="<<c[0][n-1]<<"  cn1="<<c[n-1][0]<<"  cnn="<<c[n-1][n-1]<<"  "<<qty_of_operations/(getsec()-begintime)<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking why the runtime increases as the matrix size increases?

Comment: No. I mean, why the performance  decreases. (in flops)

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? Currently there is C-code and a `cout`. Look into Boost.uBLAS as suggested by 111111.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are asking why the average number of floating-point operations per second (FLOPS) decreases as the matrix size increases.

The answer is: cache.  The "naive" approach to matrix multiplication that you are using is terrible for cache performance; as the matrix grows you will be increasing the number of cache misses.

If you're determined to write this yourself (rather than using an extant linear-algebra library), you should investigate "blocking", also known as "loop tiling".  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling.  The basic idea is that you break the operation up into smaller blocks that correspond to your cache size.

Comment: This article article goes through the effects of CPU cache on Matrix multiplication.  The article use matrix multiplication as an example and shows some modifications of the basic algorithm to get some speed improvements.  O(N^3) http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/

Answer (score 3):

I think it's more of a cache coherency issue - the format you've chosen for storage is not contiguous, has nonconstant stride and two levels of indirection. Choose a fortran/BLAS-compatible layout and then link in an industrial-strength BLAS/GEMM implementation (ACML, ATLAS) and you should see the opposite result: larger problems have higher sustained flop rates.

Multiplying matrices is a well-studied problem and there are good library options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your point:

- If `n` is bigger, then you have your last loop (using `i`, `j`, and `k`) having a `n * n * n` complexity.
- But your previous loop (with `i` and `j`) also add complexity of `n*n`

Then  the `qty_of_operation` is not what you assume. Then your performance is going down. In addition, the use of larger blocks of memory can have some penalties.

In addition, you get the "real" time, not "cpu" time, which is different, especially when more than one process is running... In Unix, simply use `time` command before starting your code.

Answer (score 0):

As the matrix size increases then there is more work (floating point calcs) for the CPU to do, that increases the time linearly (to number number of elements -- not rows or cols).

You also have more memory to traverse this means you get more cache misses when travesing the memory so the number of cycle per instruction goes up.

Finally you should check out a library like boost ublas, you are doing this the hard way when there is n need for it to be.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm

EDIT: you are also iterating though the array three times so any increase is magnified.

Comment: Actually it's O(n*n*n) not O(3n).

Comment: Here are the results of measurements:
for 20 elements 1.28287e +08 flopps
500 items for 1.54018e +08 flopps
2800 items for 2.20877e +06 flopps

Comment: that sounds about right. @dbrank I didn't say it O(3n) I worded it very badly, what I meant it that an increase has been take into account three times.